# Android App showing "This app isn't available for your device" on Goole play only for Android 11 but working for both higher and lower version

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-11

Facing an issue on Android 11 version devices only, While installation issue coming with message "This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android". Same app is working on both higher or lower version(Android 10 and Android 12 version).

STACK USED FOR ANDROID SDK VERSION

```
ext {
    androidCompileSdkVersion = 31
    androidBuildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'
    androidMinSdkVersion = 23
    androidTargetSdkVersion = 31
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ0LC.png)

Min SDK version 31 is installed and App is working on Android 12 devices, It must work on Android 11 devices also on Play store.